# HTML script onclick did not execute all functions in Google Sheet

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a HMTL script for a button to execute a series of 6 functions when clicked. The HTML script is running in Google Sheet. The Google sheet function that is executed is to download a sheet in the active spreadsheet. The issue encountered is whenever the button is clicked, it consistently execute only 5 of the 6 functions, i.e. only 5 sheets are downloaded instead of 6 sheets. How to resolve the problem so that all 6 sheets are downloaded.

HTML script:

```
<input type="button" value='ALL' onclick="download('AA'); download('BB'); download('CC'); download('DD'); download('EE'); download('FF')" />

<script>
  function download(type) {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(({ data, filename }) => {
        if (data && filename) {
          const a = document.createElement("a");
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.download = filename;
          a.href = data;
          a.click();
        }
      })
      .createDataUrl(type);
  }
</script>
```

Google sheet function:

```
function createDataUrl(type) {
  var act_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var firstSheet = act_sheet.getSheets()[0];
  var secondSheet = act_sheet.getSheets()[1];
  var thirdSheet = act_sheet.getSheets()[2];
  var fourthSheet = act_sheet.getSheets()[3];
  var fifthSheet = act_sheet.getSheets()[4];
  var sixthSheet = act_sheet.getSheets()[5];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  let url = null;
  if (type == "AA") {
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(firstSheet);
    sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=tsv&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
   } else if (type == "BB") {
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(secondSheet);
    sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=tsv&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
   } else if (type == "CC") {
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(thirdSheet);
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=tsv&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
   } else if (type == "DD") {
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(fourthSheet);
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=tsv&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
   } else if (type == "EE") {
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(fifthSheet);
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=tsv&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
  } else if (type == "FF") {
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sixthSheet);
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=tsv&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
  }

  if (url) {
    const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}` },
    }).getBlob();

    return {
      data:
        `data:${mimeTypes[type]};base64,` +
        Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes()),
      filename: `${sheet.getSheetName()}.${'tsv'}`,
    };
  }

  return { data: null, filename: null };
}
```

Haven't try anything because don't know how to resolve. Have clicked the button many times and found that the combination of the 5 sheets downloaded varies among different execution.

Comment: `google.script.run` is asynchronous process.  Which means one `google.script.run` doesn't wait for another to finish before it runs.  So the order of downloads may not be AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, FF but in any order.  As to why sheet 6 "FF" doesn't download are you sure there are 6 sheets and sheet 6 may not be "FF" as you think.  I would suggest using sheet names instead of index, unless your sure about it.  Why not make one call to the server rather than 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve from the 1st sheet to the 6th sheet in the active Spreadsheet in TSV format.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, by `onclick="download('AA'); download('BB'); download('CC'); download('DD'); download('EE'); download('FF')"`, your `download(type)` is run 6 times. But, `google.script.run` is run with the asynchronous process. (This has already been mentioned in TheWizEd's comment.) And also, unfortunately, when the endpoint of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=tsv&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}` is continuously run, an error like `429 Too Many Requests` occurs. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue.
- Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that there is no endpoint for exporting Spreadsheets in TSV format, which can be continuously requested, while there is an endpoint for exporting it in CSV format.

From the above points, if you want to retrieve 6 sheets in TSV format, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you test this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

##### HTML & Javascript side:

```html
<input type="button" value='ALL' onclick="download()"/>
<script>
  function download() {
    const filename = "sample.zip"; // This is a sample filename of the downloaded file.
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(({ data }) => {
        if (data) {
          const a = document.createElement("a");
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.download = filename;
          a.href = data;
          a.click();
        }
      })
      .createDataUrl();
  }
</script>
```

##### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function createDataUrl() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets().splice(0, 6).map(s => s.getSheetName());
  if (sheets.length == 0) {
    return { data: null };
  }
  var blobs = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ssId, { ranges: sheets, valueRenderOption: "FORMATTED_VALUE" }).valueRanges.map(({ values }, i) => Utilities.newBlob(values.map(r => r.join("\t")).join("\n"), "text/tab-separated-values", `${sheets[i]}.${'tsv'}`));
  return { data: `data:${MimeType.ZIP};base64,${Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.zip(blobs).getBytes())}` };
}
```

- When this script is run, when you open the HTML and click the button, the sheets from the 1st to the 6th sheet are exported as TSV format, and those files are zipped. And, the file is downloaded as a zip file.
- In order to retrieve the values from 6 sheets in a Spreadsheet, Sheets API is used. By this, the process cost can be reduced a little.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)